# How to use multiple keyword domains for maximum SEO benefit

Tags: seo

I have the possibility to acquire several domains around the keyword that I am interested in. It would go like: house.com, houses.com, villa.com, housing.com.

Only one of these will host a commercial website (i.e. house.com), so there any use at owning those other domains? If there is, how should I exploit them ?

Comment: You will also find a vast amount of questions regarding keywords and domains [Here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Keyword+domain) and I also recommend you research Domain penalties when using 'exact' keyword vs branding.

Comment: I understand the redirection issue, but here I am wondering how can I leverage these domains for maximum SEO benefit